# Need help at evaluating a multi-label classifier

Tags: precision-recall, multilabel

What would you say about the performance of a multi-label (8 labels) classifier based on the plots below and knowing its mean log-loss on training (N = 1700) and validation (N = 700) sets (1.6 and 1.4 respectively)?

[image]

[image]